# Create a table and calculate sum

Tags: shell, for-loop

I have to write a script that takes a parameter `n` and creates a table of size `n` filled with 1,2,3,4,..,n.

I want now to display the sum of all the cases.

```
#!bin/bash

for i in $1 do
    tab[i]=$i
    echo "$tab[i]
done
```

Comment: You need to better explain what you are trying to do exactly. What do you mean "table"? What do you mean "size n"? What do you mean "all the cases"? Does this need to be written in "shell"?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. Please clarify and give some examples.

Comment: table = array ( sorry ) , in a shell script ( bash yes) for exemple if in argument we have 5 , I have to creat an array of 5 in which I put 1,2,3,4,5 then i dislay the sum ( 1+2+3+4+5 , I display 15 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$#" != 1 ]
then
  echo $0 SIZE
  exit
fi

# We can use one “for” loop to both fill the array, and calculate the sum.
for ((z=1; z<=$1; z++))
do
  # Here we are creating our array “y” and adding a new value to it, “z”
  y+=($z)
  # Here we will use “let”. This is the same as using ((x+=z)), it is a way
  # to perform arithmetic on variables. In this case we are adding “z”
  # (current array value) to the total “x”
  let x+=z
done

declare -p y x
```

Input

```
7
```

Output

```
declare -a y='([0]="1" [1]="2" [2]="3" [3]="4" [4]="5" [5]="6" [6]="7")'
declare -- x="28"
```

You can tweak the output, I just used `declare` so you could see everything
clearly.